# Async play sound in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, asynchronous

how can I load asynchronously a sound in javascript ?

I want to play in loop severals sounds ans calculus in parallel.
This is the timeline :

```
     10 seconds           7 seconds           10 seconds
|--------------------|------------------|--------------------|--- etc
| Sound1 playing     |Sound2 playing    | Sound1 playing     |--- etc 
| Do a calculus      |Do a calculus     | Do a calculus      |--- etc
```

Sound1 and Sound2 last less than 5 seconds
Calculs last 1 second.

How can i do that in javascript ?

I must use Workers in HTML5 ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried creating distinct `<audio>` elements? It would only seem logical to me that one element only can play one sound at once

Comment: _"the timer pauses when sound is playing"_ - As in, there is a total of 15 seconds between calls to `myfunction()`, the specified 10 seconds plus the 5 seconds of the sound?

Comment: @Scanpat: And that doesn't work with the above code? What happens instead?

Comment: My previous comment was an attempt to clarify what you meant. Are you saying that where normally `setInterval` would call your function every 10 seconds, if the function causes a sound to play the _next_ invocation of the function will be delayed by the length of the sound?

Comment: @nnnnnn : I have updated my post in order to be clear

Comment: @Bergi : have updated my post in order to be clear

Comment: @nnnnnn : you have an idea to help me ?

Comment: I must use Workers in HTML5 ?

Comment: No. Workers do not have access to the DOM, and cannot play sounds. Forget about them.

Comment: @Bergi So what is the best solution ?

Comment: @Scanpat.  If one of the answers below is helpful, you should mark it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 9):

Playing sounds asynchronously in JS is in fact pretty simple. You just have to create `new Audio`s and `play()` them right away instead of `play()`ing global `Audio` objects. Here's an example:

```
function playSoundAsync(url){
    new Audio(url).play();
}
```

So in your case, your code would look like this (with a hack involving `setInterval`s and `setTimeout`s for syncing up the sounds):

```js
// For simplicity I'll use MP3 files readily available on the Internet
var sound1url = 'https://audio.code.org/win3.mp3';
var sound2url = 'https://audio.code.org/failure3.mp3';
var calculusUrl = 'https://audio.code.org/failure1.mp3';

setInterval(function() {
    new Audio(sound1url).play();
    new Audio(calculusUrl).play();
}, 17000);
setTimeout(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        new Audio(sound2url).play();
        new Audio(calculusUrl).play();
    }, 17000);
}, 10000);
```

```html
<button onclick="new Audio(sound1url).play();">Play sound1 individually</button>
<button onclick="new Audio(sound2url).play();">Play sound2 individually</button>
<button onclick="new Audio(calculusUrl).play();">Play calculus individually</button>
```

In addition, you might notice this when you click the <kbd>Play ${sound} individually</kbd> buttons rapidly: A new playback of ${sound} starts without waiting for or interrupting the current ${sound} playback! This allows you to create an acoustic mess like this:

```js
var cacophony = setInterval(function(){new Audio('https://audio.code.org/win3.mp3').play();}, 25);
```

```html
<button onclick="clearInterval(cacophony);">Click here to stop this cacophony</button>
```

Comment: **Note to anyone considering downvoting this:** If you're downvoting because I didn't follow some JS convention(s), then could you **please** tell me which convention(s) did I break?

Comment: Won't the always 'new' object hog down memory? I tried using that with bouncing balls, and making sounds when they bounce the walls, the memory usage increases rapidly if using more balls.

Comment: You need to handle promise unless you get a error like this `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException`

Answer (score 5):

You can easily make your audio play async (without using a timer) by using JS promises and async functions.

```
// makes playing audio return a promise
function playAudio(audio){
  return new Promise(res=>{
    audio.play()
    audio.onended = res
  })
}

// how to call
async function test(){
  const audio = new Audio('<url>')
  await playAudio(audio)
  // code that will run after audio finishes...
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

I built on dorukayhan's answer, but my sounds were going to repeat thousands of times.  I was afraid that creating multiple new Audio tags would eventually crash the system.

So I created a function that cycles through a bunch of existing audio tags.

The  tags go somewhere in your HTML.  I put mine before the end </body> tag.  My sounds were short bleeps, so 10 tags were enough to play smooth, but you can experiment with the number of audio tags.

```
<audio id="audio0"></audio>
<audio id="audio1"></audio>
<audio id="audio2"></audio>
<audio id="audio3"></audio>
<audio id="audio4"></audio>
<audio id="audio5"></audio>
<audio id="audio6"></audio>
<audio id="audio7"></audio>
<audio id="audio8"></audio>
<audio id="audio9"></audio>
```

```
//declare a global counter in your script
<script>
var audiocount=0;
/*other code...*/

/*call to play sound*/
Playsound('mysound.wav')

/*other code*.../

/*add function to play sounds*/
function Playsound(MySoundPlay)
{
   /*id() is a shortcut for getElementById*/
   id('audio'+audiocount).src=MySoundPlay
   id('audio'+audiocount).play()
   audiocount++;
   /*reset your counter according to no. of audio tags you created*/
   if (audiocount>9){audiocount=0;}  
}

/*shortcut function for getElementById*/
function id(myID){return document.getElementById(myID)}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are searching for [`window.setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval).